# How to get Xdebug running on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, xdebug

I just pushed a new deployment to a staging instance on Heroku, which failed, and now I am getting a 500 error from my site.

composer.json

```
{
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.16",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
        "ext-memcached": "*",
        "ext-apcu": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-gettext": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "ext-mysql": "*",
        "ext-xdebug": ">=2.4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
    }
}
```

New PHP code:

```
// STARTS DEBUG
xdebug_start_function_monitor(['session_start']);

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    var_dump(xdebug_get_monitored_functions(), ini_get('session.auto_start'));
});
// ENDS DEBUG
```

Heroku build log:

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - php (5.5.38)
       - ext-gd (bundled with php)
       - ext-gettext (bundled with php)
       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
       - ext-mysql (bundled with php)
       - ext-soap (bundled with php)
       - ext-apcu (4.0.11)
       - ext-memcached (2.2.0)
       - apache (2.4.20)
       - nginx (1.8.1)
 !     WARNING: Your 'composer.lock' is not up to date with the latest
       changes in 'composer.json'. To ensure you are not getting stale
       dependencies, run 'composer update' on your machine and commit
       any changes to Git before pushing again.
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.2.2 2016-11-03 17:43:15
       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.6.1)
           Loading from cache

         - Installing guzzle/guzzle (v3.9.2)
           Loading from cache

         - Installing aws/aws-sdk-php (2.7.12)
           Loading from cache

       Generating optimized autoload files
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
       - New Relic detected, installed ext-newrelic
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 112.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v792
       https://XXX.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

As far as I can see from the build logs, the reason why it's failing it's because Xdebug is not getting installed, even though I've specified it in composer.json.

**How do I install Xdebug on Heroku?**

Comment: It looks to me like the build completed successfully. HTTP 500 is a generic error message. You should [check your application logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval) and see what they say.

Comment: @Chris I've taken a look at the applications logs, which didn't tell me anything, but I've confirmed that the reason why it ain't working is because XDebug doesn't get installed (even though it's in composer.json). I've confirmed that XDebug is indeed not installed by this error message: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function xdebug_start_function_monitor() in ...`

Comment: @Chris, I did, it's the first block of the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I saw it as soon as I commented. It looks like your `composer.lock` is out of date. Did you update it to include Xdebug, e.g. with something like `composer update ext-xdebug`, and commit that change?

Comment: @Chris I did that just now, and now I'm getting this error in the build log: `composer.json/composer.lock dev-45eb81d8c0b0eef239fa1554baa18cba requires ext-xdebug * -> no matching package found.` (as you can see, I've even removed the Xdebug version constraint from composer.json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Xdebug is not supported on Heroku. Heroku's documentation provides [six lists of extensions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions):

- Three lists for PHP 5.5 and 5.6:

  - Built-in extensions that are automatically enabled
  - Built-in extensions that can be enabled through `composer.json`
  - Third-party extensions that can be enabled through `composer.json`
- Three corresponding lists for PHP 7

None of them lists Xdebug.